# Excel corrupted file when change culture

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I use C# .Net 4.0 to produce an excel workbook with NPOI.
When I set *us-EN* as culture it works' fine, instead when I change the culture to *it-IT* I receive the following message:

*Excel found unreadable content in '[filename].xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.*

When I click Yes, the excel file opens well. It happens with each version of excel.
I use the following piece of code to change the culture and initialize the workbook:

```
   var culture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

   var xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Someone can help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your excel spreadsheet has some invalid format data that doesn't support it-IT culture.  Try to set the regional settings of your spreadsheet then.  I have found a link which might help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/globalization-and-localization-of-excel-solutions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Unfortunately the excel file is corrupted even if it's empty. Could be related with some other setting?

Comment: Okay @Sergio Gentile, that doesn't sound good.  Anyway, I was thinking maybe you could initialize your `XSSFWorkbook` before instantiating a `new CultureInfo()`.